# When I generate the archives using Freezed package I received this message: [SEVERE] freezed:freezed on [my archive directory]: Stack Overflow

Tags: flutter, freezed, flutter-freezed

I'm using different packages what uses the freezed generator, including modular with modular_codegen, when I generate the file's running the archives generator command, I receive this message

```
[SEVERE] freezed:freezed on [my archives directory].dart:

Stack Overflow
```

the message appear in different contexts using @freezed and @Injectable(), before nullsafety all was running okay

Comment: Hi, Please add your models codes

Comment: I can't do that, the files are secret of the enterprise, nothing can be posted outside the company systems :/